# BigQuery Enumerate-like function on JSON Array

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to turn a JSON encoded list into a native BigQuery Array, ideally this would end up being a list of tuples or dictionaries with value, position entries. Hence the reference to the python enumerate functionality.

i.e.

```
[(idx, elem) for idx, elem in enumerate(json_list_string)]

[{'pos':idx, 'value':elem} for idx, elem in enumerate(json_list_string)]
```

The first part of turning the json into an array I already solved using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315359/how-to-convert-an-array-extracted-from-a-json-string-field-to-a-bigquery-repeate)

**Edit:**

```
WITH
  my_ids AS (
  SELECT 'xyz' as grp, '["7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5", "chg3g33f26949hg6067d", "g477e5973ec04g7c3232", "0de1ec83304d761he786", "3c1h1f153530g90g35c2", "946637g145h48322686f"]' as ids
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' as grp, '["7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5", "chg3g33fdsfsdfs49hg6067d", "g477e5973ec04g7c3232", "0de1ec83304d761he786", "3c1h1f153530g90g35c2", "946637g145h48322686f"]' as ids
  )

SELECT
  *
FROM my_ids
```

In an ideal world I would get an output like:

```
xyz, 7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5, 1
xyz, chg3g33f26949hg6067d, 2
...
abc, 946637g145h48322686f, 6
```

Please note, that the lists can be rather long (up to 24 entries and I kinda don't want to hardcode all the paths)

**Edit2: (Possible Solution)**

```
WITH
  my_ids AS (
  SELECT 'xyz' as grp, '["7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5", "chg3g33f26949hg6067d", "g477e5973ec04g7c3232", "0de1ec83304d761he786", "3c1h1f153530g90g35c2", "946637g145h48322686f"]' as ids
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' as grp, '["7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5", "chg3g33fdsfsdfs49hg6067d", "g477e5973ec04g7c3232", "0de1ec83304d761he786", "3c1h1f153530g90g35c2", "946637g145h48322686f"]' as ids
  ),

  as_list AS (SELECT
    *,
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ids,'$'), r'[\[\]\"]', ''), ',') AS split_items,
    GENERATE_ARRAY(1, ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ids,'$'), r'[\[\]\"]', ''), ','))) AS positions
  FROM my_ids)

SELECT grp, ids, positions[OFFSET(off)] as pos
FROM as_list, unnest(split_items) as ids WITH OFFSET off
```

Comment: please provide simplified example of input and desired output and more details on what kind of query you are looking for

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant updated, does this make it clearer?

Comment: just post your solution as an answer! or it is still not what you wanted?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yea, I guess I will do that. Was wondering if there was a more natural way of achieving what I want. This feels kinda ugly :D

Comment: i can see another less verbose option - will post shortly... posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_ids` AS (
  SELECT 'xyz' AS grp, '["7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5", "chg3g33f26949hg6067d", "g477e5973ec04g7c3232", "0de1ec83304d761he786", "3c1h1f153530g90g35c2", "946637g145h48322686f"]' AS ids UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' AS grp, '["7f9f98fh9g4ef393d3h5", "chg3g33fdsfsdfs49hg6067d", "g477e5973ec04g7c3232", "0de1ec83304d761he786", "3c1h1f153530g90g35c2", "946637g145h48322686f"]' AS ids
)
SELECT grp, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY OFFSET) pos
FROM `project.dataset.my_ids`, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ids,'$'), r'[\[\]\"]', ''), ',')) id WITH OFFSET
```

Comment: indeed much cleaner, funnily enough I did have a version like this before moving to offset. I kept running into Resource Exceeded Errors when applying this logic to a ~60GB.

There is another window function in my pipeline, which is also causing Resource Exceeded problems right now. So I can't say for certain.

Can you say anything about how the two approaches compare in terms of resource usage?

Comment: Any idea how I can overcome the resource exceeded with the over function? I remember in the back of my head that there is something about double partitioning.

Comment: It is quite not possible to answer this in comments - I would suggested you to post new question with specific use case and all relevant details so we can help you

Comment: wouldn't the following be cleaner? I will shortly write the followup question.
SELECT grp, id, pos + 1 as pos
FROM `project.dataset.my_ids`, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(ids,'$'), r'[\[\]\"]', ''), ',')) id WITH OFFSET as pos

or just accept, that the indexing is zero-based, in essence the "WITH OFFSET" was what I was initially asking for!!

Comment: this is the standalone question btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565523/query-failed-with-error-resource-exhausted-order-by-without-order-by